# How do you tell Inno Setup when installing multi-language shortcuts to get rid of the other language?

Tags: inno-setup

I have Inno Setup with multi-language configured and have custom messages.   Some of those are used for creating the shortcuts.  However, if I reinstall and choose a different language, the old shortcuts still exist and a new set is created.

How can I have Inno Setup track the icon based on the target rather than the name so when the shortcut is created, it overwrites the other language with the current language?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no easy solution for this. Some of your options are:

1. Always delete all (other) localized versions of the icon.
2. Remember what icon have you created the last time and delete that.
3. Iterate all icons, finding those that has the same target (as you suggested) – though this would delete even user-created icons, what is wrong.
4. Uninstall the existing installed version before installing (as suggested by @Bill_Stewart).